# Compiling Allegro source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, allegro

I am trying to build a C# project (downloaded code) in Visual Studio Express 2008. I get the error (*my translation*):

> The type or namespace name "Allegro"
>   couldn't be found.

for the line

```
using Allegro;
```

I know the 2D graphics library Allegro, of course, but I can't find much information on how to use it in C#. It is being used for visualization in the project I am trying to compile.

I also get the warning

> This reference couldn't be resolved.
>   The Universal assembly couldn't be
>   found.

I haven't been working with C# before and and I barely know Visual Studio Express. These are newbie mistakes - but I just need a fast solution for this problem. Could someone provide me with a short step-by-step solution?

Comment: Where is your "Allegro.dll"? The compiler needs to find it. So it needs to be where the project expects it. The project file contains a list of referenced assemblies, so you need to check the path there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove old reference of Allegro.dll from project and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Allegro isn't a .NET library; it's written in traditional unmanaged C. If you downloaded code that references an Allegro C# library, then perhaps the author was using some unofficial C# bindings. If so, the solution is to find that additional library and use it.

Otherwise, there is no short, step-by-step solution. You would need to use `DllImport` on each function that you need, and follow the standard practices for using unmanaged C DLLs in C#.